# Summation of odd power

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

How do I find the explicit formula for the following summation:
$x^1 + x^3 + x^5 + ... $

I know $1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + ...  = 1/(1-x)$, but this is quite a different series.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

$$x+x^3+x^5+....=x(1+x^2+x^4+....)=x(1+(x^2)^1+(x^2)^2+(x^2)^3+....)=\frac {x}{1-x^2}$$

Comment: Thanks! why didnt I think of this?!

Comment: So clever, Amr! :-)

Comment: Thank you. But I am not that clever really for posting this answer

Answer (score 6):

Not much different,$$x^1+x^3+x^5\cdots=x(1+x^2+(x^2)^2+\cdots)$$

Comment: Edited the formula, as it was not correct...