# The sum of series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have the series

$x_{2n-1}:=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+...+\frac{1}{2^{2n-1}}=1+\frac{2}{3}\cdot(1-\frac{1}{4^n}).$ But why?

I found that the sum of odds power can be so calculate:

$x+x^3+x^5...=x(1+(x^2)^1+(x^2)^2..=\frac{x}{1-x^2}$. If I apply this to my series, then I get $\frac{4}{3}$ because $1+\frac{1}{2} \cdot(1+(\frac{1}{2^2})^1+(\frac{1}{2^2})^2...+(\frac{1}{2^{2}})^{n-2}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{1-\frac{1}{2^2}}=1+\frac{1}{2} \cdot(\frac{4}{6})=1+\frac{1}{3}=\frac{4}{3}$

So something doesn't work! I will be grateful for help!

Comment: What you have is a finite sum, not a series.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Derivation

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/252992

Comment: @user1046533 ok, thank you! now I got $1+\frac{1}{2} \cdot(2-\frac{1}{2^n})$, but it is not the right answer. Where do I have mistake?

Comment: @user1046533 I saw this link, so its why I know about odd powers. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$
\begin{array}{l}
 x_{2n - 1}  = 1 + \frac{1}{{2^1 }} + \frac{1}{{2^3 }} + \frac{1}{{2^5 }} +  \cdots \frac{1}{{2^{2n - 1} }} =  \\ 
  = 1 + \frac{1}{{2^1 }}\left( {1 + \frac{1}{{2^2 }} + \frac{1}{{2^4 }} +  \cdots \frac{1}{{2^{2n - 2} }}} \right) \\ 
 \end{array}
$$
Now
$$
1 + \frac{1}{{2^2 }} + \frac{1}{{2^4 }} +  \cdots \frac{1}{{2^{2n - 2} }} = 1 + \frac{1}{{2^2 }} + \frac{1}{{\left( {2^2 } \right)^2 }} +  \cdots \frac{1}{{\left( {2^2 } \right)^{n - 1} }}
$$
Hence
$$
\begin{array}{l}
 x_{2n - 1}  = 1 + \frac{1}{2}\left( {1 + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{{4^2 }} +  \cdots \frac{1}{{4^{n - 1} }}} \right) =  \\ 
  = 1 + \frac{1}{2}\left( {\frac{{1 - \frac{1}{{4^{n - 1 + 1} }}}}{{1 - \frac{1}{4}}}} \right) =  \\ 
  = 1 + \frac{2}{3}\left( {1 - \frac{1}{{4^n }}} \right) \\ 
 \end{array}
$$